# Does sprintf() modify variable across function?

Tags: c

I use sprintf() to fill my string, but when I'm not done, I found something strange, the var which names test can be modified even it is a argument, I thought it was just like a Rvalue when calling function, or here is somewhere I didn't notice, and the following is my code and output.

Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void Encap(char str[9])
{
    printf("%s\n", str);
    sprintf(str, "hi e");
    printf("%s\n%p\n", str, &str);
}

int main()
{
    char test[9] = "ABC";

    printf("%s\n", test);
    Encap(test);
    printf("%s\n%p\n", test, &test);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
ABC
ABC
hi e
0061FF10
hi e
0061FF27
```

Comment: In one case you are pronting address of variable `str`, in other - `test`. Different variables - different addresses.

Comment: `&str` is not the value you might expect... as `char str[9]` is indeed `char* str`.

Comment: Arrays are passed to a function as a pointer; the content that the pointer points at can be modified, as you demonstrate.  This is basic C theory (and practice).  There shouldn't be any surprise here.

Comment: When you pass array - you actually pass a pointer to the first element. So your string is modified since function works with pointer. You probably should remove C++ tag

Comment: `sprintf` takes a [variable argument list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments). Variable argument lists are kinda weird and do some things you might not expect like data type conversions and trying to use a `string` as an integer instead of giving an error message. Worth reading up on them.

Comment: @Feng. Ma you need to learn the C basics. Start from the good C book

Comment: Thanks for everyone's replied, my basic concepts really having some problem haha, cuz the professor thought I knows basic concepts of C, and made me do something complicated than this even I told him concept problems. Anyway, I'm learning basics in the meantime, thanks for recommendation and explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing pointer to function, It will surely change value at the memory location.
As you are passing pointer, another copy of pointer will be created and which will be used in function.(Whenever we call to a function, copy of variable is made and operations are done on that copy variable). Here the variable is of type pointer, hence another pointer variable will be created which will be pointing to same memory locations as pointed by test but will be having different address.
That's why two different memory address gets printed as you are printing address of two different pointers.

Comment: @Feng.Ma in the function, remove the `&` because the function was already passed the pointer of interest. So `printf("%s\n%p\n", str, str);` What you are doing, is printing the address of the function argument (probably its location on the stack) - not the value of the pointer itself. Actually `printf("%s\n%p\n", str, (void*)str);` is more correct.

Comment: ok, I got it, the key is the arg passing is ptr, thanks for answer.

Answer (score 3):

You declare an array `test`, and you pass it to the function `Encap`.  Your question is a little unclear, but there are two things which may be surprising you:

1. Within the function `Encap`, you are modifying the contents of the array.
2. After the function `Encap` returns, back in the caller, the modifications to the `test` array persist.

(You also asked about "rvalue", which can be an important concept, but it doesn't apply here in the way that you expect.)

The reason this works the way it does is because of two different things:

1. When you pass the array `test` to the function `Encap`, you do not pass the entire value of the array. what actually gets passed is just a pointer to the array;s first element.
2. Within the function `Encap`, you are not modifying the pointer that was passed, instead, you are modifying the memory that the pointer points to.  You are using the pointer as a value (a pointer value) to know where the memory is that you should modify -- and this ends up being the `test` array up in `main()`.

Comment: he need a C beginners book not any explanations as he does not know the basics

Comment: after reading the explanations, I catch some misc but important points, thanks for being so patient to a beginner.